# AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tickColor' with config ''

Tags: android

I have updated version for  buildToolsVersion "30.0.2" & compileSdkVersion 30 and worked fine but now I have added aar library and getting error. Even I cleaned the project and don't have attr file in resource folder

Previously  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

Now  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')

After added this plugin getting error    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'